# Get request are working fine but Post requests aren't working

Tags: node.js, windows, api, windows-firewall, hapi

I have cloned my production code onto my windows local machine and setup a local environment for the code. My GET api's are working fine, but my POST and PUT api's are not working. Actually, if I send any POST or PUT request through postman, thunderclient, or through the browser itself, the requests are not reaching the server. It doesn't get any response from the server, nor does the server get any type of response, nor does it generate any errors. But if I close the server, then the request replies with "no response from the server."

And I have also tried this in Ubuntu. In Ubuntu, this works fine. So, I am very confused about what the issue is in Windows with that project itself, because other projects are working fine.

I am using node as a server and I am using the hapi framework.

Comment: lower your node version to 14 and then check